# What is the lifetime of shares created with STYPE_TEMPORARY?

Tags: winapi, cifs

Or, more generally, what does specifying `STYPE_TEMPORARY` do?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc462916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s "A temporary share." is not helpful.

What are the lifetime guarantees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [protocol documentation for SMB on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247110%28v=prot.13%29.aspx) includes *slightly* more information:

> STYPE_TEMPORARY: A temporary share that is not persisted for creation each time the file server initializes.

...and [this page on NetrShareAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247275%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx) explains more of the expected semantics:

> If the **STYPE_TEMPORARY** field is set in shi*_type, **Share.IsPersistent** MUST be set to FALSE. Otherwise, **Share.IsPersistent** MUST be set to TRUE.
>
> If **Share.IsPersistent** is TRUE, the server MUST persist the **Share** to a persistent configuration store. If a share with the same ShareName already exists in the store, the preexisting entry MUST be overwritten with this entry.

...but mapping that to how specific implementations of the protocol behave is another story.

Comment: Oh well I think using that tiny bit of information I can infer that it's related to the lifetime of the SERVER service. Thanks, that's actually close what I was hoping for!